# Find a file 1 folder level down

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.path

I am trying to get full_path of `places.sqlite` file present in `'%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<random_folder>\places.sqlite'` using Python OS module. The issue as you can see that `<random_folder>` has a random name and there could be multiple folders inside the `Profiles` folder.

How do I navigate/find the path to the `places.sqlite` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would ideally want to go through each folder to search for this file. In terminal 'locate file_name' command would do this for you. In python file you can use the following command:

```py
import os


db_path = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), r'Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles')


def find_file(file_name, path):
    for root_folder, directory, file_names in os.walk(path):
        if file_name in file_names:
            return os.path.join(root_folder, file_name)


print(find_file('places.sqlite', db_path))
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.walk` gives a list of all files in a path recusivly. Use it to search for `'places.sqlite'` as follows.

```
path = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("%APPDATA%\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\"):
    if "places.sqlite" in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, 'places.sqlite')
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `os` module to list out all directories in `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\`

loop over the directories until you find places.sqlite file (also using os module)

Comment: There is a built-in function for that. `os.walk()`

Answer (score 0):

A `glob` might be simpler as in this case one expects the file to be there in level below the `Profiles` folder or not there at all.

```py
import os
import pathlib

profiles = pathlib.Path(os.environ["APPDATA"]) / "Mozilla" / "Firefox" / "Profiles"
# rglob will recursively search as well
if places := list(profiles.rglob("places.sqlite")):
    print(places[0]) # will print the sqllite file path
    with places[0].open() as f:
        # ....
```